# JwtBearerAuthentication with ASP.Net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

ever since this last update of RC1 I am not able to get my MVC app to be able to read and authenticate jwt Tokens.  I used to have working code that looked like this in `Startup.cs`:

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
 {
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new MyJwtOptions());
    ...
 }
```

and then also had this:

```
public MyJwtOptions()
{
   var issuer = "https://issuer.com";
   var audience = "https://www.audience.com";
   var key = Convert.FromBase64String("secretKey");
            AllowedAudiences = new[] {audience};
            IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new[] {new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, key)};
}
```

the error come here:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication()
```

I searched all over trying to find why this is no longer compatable with DNX 4.5 and DNX Core 5.0.  Intellisense tries to help me out and tells me

> "You must add reference to Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions"

doing that does not  help at all . I have found other answers that suggest to add reference to `Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OAuthBearer` , also no luck there.

I found another answer that suggests trying it like this:

```
services.Configure<OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions>(bearer =>
{
    bearer.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey = key;
    bearer.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience = TokenAudience;
    bearer.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = TokenIssuer;
});
```

the problem with that is I don't know how to create a `SecureKey` for the `IssuerSigningKey`

Has anybody else successfully gotten this working with the newest version of Asp.net 5 fc1-final ?

### Update

Just about every example I find is for apps that are creating and validating the jwt tokens on their own.  In my case I'm using Thinktecture server to validate the tokens.  That is why I need `audience` and `issuer` and why I am a little lost trying to create the `RsaKey`. Because the key can't just be something I create locally in an XML file, it needs to be authenticated as a trusted app on the Thinktecture server

Comment: Many people use XML like you. But optionally you could create a self-signed certificate and include it to your project.

Comment: @vzayko my problem is I am used to using a string key to verify my app is a trusted client app.  Now I need a X.509 certificate , do you know of any examples that convert the trusted app key into a certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution to my question in the rc-1 release.   From posting another question on here I learned that this has been resolved with the rs-2 update.

If you need rs-2 update before the offical release in Feburary of '16 you can run `dvnm update -u` to get the latest nightly builds of rc-2

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OAuthBearer was renamed to JwtBearer.
https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/87

Comment: I realize they changed some namespaces.  My problem is that I used to use a string key to authenticate a trusted client.   Now it looks like they require a certificate.  Do you know how to convert the string key into a client certificate?